# need to find the attribute name in the string

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'm trying to capture the last attribute in the line in Java. Please tweak the below code and help me to find "battr". For instance i named attributes like "attr" and "battr", but it can be anything.

```
System.out.println("<tag attr=\"val1\" battr=\"val2\"></tag>".replaceAll(".*([a-z]+\\s*=).*","$1"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
System.out.println("<tag attr=\"val1\" battr=\"val2\"></tag>".replaceAll(".*(\\s([a-z])+\\s*=).*", "$1")
            .replace("=", "").trim());
```

**EDIT**:

You can use positive lookahead for you requirements:

```
System.out.println("<tag attr=\"val1\" battr=\"val2\"></tag>".replaceAll(".*((\\s|^)([a-z])+(?==)).*", "$1").trim());
```

For more info: [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please also tweak the same to work for below string as well. attr=\"val1\" battr=\"val2\"></tag>

Comment: Have you tried the solution? It's already working for the string you mentioned. Just add this `.replaceAll(".*(\\s([a-z])+\\s*=).*", "$1").replace("=", "").trim()` to the end of the string.

Comment: yes the regex is working fine.. but fails if the line doesn't start with string "<tag" and there is the only one attribute which doesn't start with space like "battr=\"val2\"></tag>"

Comment: Ok. But  `"battr=\"val2\"></tag>"` is not a valid attribute string.

Comment: I'll add more details... 1. the last attribute may start with the <tag 2.the last attribute may come with <tag and with one another attribute 3.the last attribute alone can occur in the line